# How to get the radial distance to the boundary given a point in ITK?

Tags: itk

I'm loading a 3D CT model and doing thinning algorithms on it. Now I'd like to calculate how much thinning the algorithms do. How can I know the distances between skeleton points and their nearest/farthest boundary points?

Answer (score 1):

Compute the [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) of the skeleton points and boundary points (stored as a binary mask). Your answer lies therin.